# Python Beautifulsoup XML Tags with Same Name

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

Suppose I have the following minimal xml with a nested hierarchy.  How can I isolate the first occurrence and then isolate the subsequent, nested occurrences?

```
<test name='something'>
<tag max='10' min='20'>
    <tag max='5' min='20'/>
    <tag max='5' min='20'/>
</first>
```

Ideally, I would be able to parse out the information from the first tag and then parse the information from the nested tags.

I have tried utilizing the `contents` of the first tag, but I get all nested tags as well.

Expected output would be:

1. `<tag max='10' min='20'>`
2. `<tag max='5' min='20'/>
    <tag max='5' min='20'/>`

Comment: Provide more details like expected output and your inputs

Comment: You are not clear what you want , first provide better xml content as your xml seems clearly broken and proper output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried my best with the XML you provided. I assume you provided an incomplete XML.

I used the `decompose()` function in BeautifulSoup to help achieve your goal.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

data = '''
<test name='something'>
<tag max='10' min='20'>
    <tag max='5' min='20'/>
    <tag max='5' min='20'/>
</first>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
[print(i) for i in soup.find_all('tag', max='5')]
print('*********************************')
[i.decompose() for i in soup.find_all('tag', max='5')]
print(soup.find('tag', max='10'))
```

Output:

```
<tag max="5" min="20"></tag>
<tag max="5" min="20"></tag>
*********************************
<tag max="10" min="20">


</tag>
```

Comment: I do believe the .decompose() function is what I'm looking for.  The parent tag having the same tag name as its children is throwing me off.  I will investigate the .decompose() function further.  And, yes, it is an incomplete xml, just a snippet of a much larger document.